# Does Bandcamp support multi-factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, bandcamp

I don't see an option in the settings.

I have a [fan account](https://get.bandcamp.help/hc/en-us/articles/360062102514-I-already-have-a-fan-account-can-I-create-an-artist-account-), mind you (i.e. a user; with over a dozen purchases).

Comment: Look at https://get.bandcamp.help/hc/en-us, more specifically at [Help > Fan Accounts](https://get.bandcamp.help/hc/en-us/sections/360001591073-Fan-accounts)

Comment: @Rubén there doesn't appear to be any related documentation. Will this question remain closed after adding the help pages as sources? I've also contacted the support, but adding their response would fall under "original research".

Comment: Not all questions about Web applications are a good fit for this site, no matter how much effort could be put into them. Questions should be about using a Web application. Currently, this question is not about using bandcamp but about its features, more specifically, if a feature is supported. As you already did, these questions should be addressed to Bandcamp developers directly.  Since this is not a discussion forum, you could add what you have learned from the support response as part of your continued research effort or to the bandcamp tag wiki.

Comment: By the way, currently there is an experiment of running a Discussions feature. This is being done in the NLP Collective of Stack Overflow depending on the results it might be possible to have some form of discussions on the public Q&A platform eventually. For more details see https://stackoverflow.co/labs/discussions/.

Comment: The current local option for asking for help for something like confirming that a feature is missing is to use the [chat].